# Angular5 canactivate guard :Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am trying to implement simple `canActivate`  in my `Auth` service

```
import {CanActivate,ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
export class Auth implements CanActivate{
    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
      ): Observable<boolean> {

            return Observable.of(true);
      }
}
```

got this error

> ERROR in src/app/modules/user/auth.ts(13,14): error TS2420: Class
>   'Auth' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.   Types of
>   property 'canActivate' are incompatible.
>       Type '(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => Observable' is not assignable to
>   type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) =>
>   boolean | Promise | Obser...'.
>         Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
>           Type 'RouterStateSnapshot' is not assignable to type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'.
>             Types of property 'url' are incompatible.
>               Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UrlSegment[]'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the declaration of state: should be RouterStateSnapshot

```
interface CanActivate { 
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
               state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of `state` to be `RouterStateSnapshot`. That is the only thing the compiler complains about.